# refresh gallery on Android Q

Tags: java, android, android-mediascanner, android-10.0

After saving the video to internal storage using `getExternalFilesDir`, I'm able to find it, if I go to **Files Explorer app > Videos > from the menu (Show Internal Storage)** :

[image]

But I can't find it in the gallery.

**Create Path :**

```
private void getPath() {
        String videoFileName = "vidoe_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            File imageFile = null;
            File storageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                    "folder");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                success = storageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                imageFile = new File(storageDir, videoFileName);
                savedVideoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            }

        } else {
            File storageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
                            + "/folder");
            boolean success = true;
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                success = storageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                File videoFile = new File(storageDir, videoFileName);
                savedVideoPath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
    }
```

**refresh Gallery :**

```
 private void galleryRefresh(String savedVideoPath) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(savedVideoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```